# How to consume messages from a Topic ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to work with topics on ActiveMQ Artemis.

I have created a Multicast Address and a Multicast Queue inside this Address.

Created 2 routes with Apache Camel to connect in this Topic, but when I post message only one Route consume the message and when I post another message, the secont Route that consume this message message.

Below the code and the output.

```
public class CamelRoutes {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory connection = new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616", "admin", "admin");

    CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camel.addComponent("amq", JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connection));

    camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("amq:TEST.TOPIC")
        .routeId("Route1")
        .log("ROUTE1: ${body}");
      }
    });
    camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("amq:TEST.TOPIC")
        .routeId("Route2")
        .log("ROUTE2: ${body}");
      }
    });
    camel.start();
    Thread.sleep(20000000);
  }
}
```

```
2019-02-11 16:35:42 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.TOPIC]] INFO  Route1:159 - ROUTE1: {"message":1}
2019-02-11 16:35:45 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[TEST.TOPIC]] INFO  Route2:159 - ROUTE2: {"message":2}
2019-02-11 16:35:48 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.TOPIC]] INFO  Route1:159 - ROUTE1: {"message":3}
2019-02-11 16:35:51 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[TEST.TOPIC]] INFO  Route2:159 - ROUTE2: {"message":4}
2019-02-11 16:35:54 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[TEST.TOPIC]] INFO  Route1:159 - ROUTE1: {"message":5}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are consuming from the queue, not from the topic. 
You need to correct your consumer's URI scheme.

Change your consumer to:

```
from("amq:topic:TEST.TOPIC");
```

---

This is how you can create queue consumer :

```
from("amq:queue:YOUR.QUEUE.NAME);
// or as queue is default value
from("amq:YOUR.QUEUE.NAME);
```

This is how you can create topic consumer :

```
from("amq:topic.YOUR.TOPIC.NAME);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Worked. I checked and he created 2 "queues", one for each consumer. And I just send the message to the Address and all consumers get the message. Thanks.